# Using VotingClassifier with other classifiers inside a Sklearn Pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, imblearn

I want to use the `VotingClassifier` inside a `sklearn Pipeline`, where I defined a set of classifiers ..

I got some intuition from this question: [Using `VotingClassifier` in Sklearn Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46793110/using-votingclassifier-in-sklearn-pipeline) to build the code below, but in this question each of the classifiers are defined in an independent Pipeline .. I don't want to use it in this way, where I have a set of features are prepared before and its not a good idea to repeat the generation of these features in multi Pipelines with different classsifiers (Time-consuming process)!

How could I achieve that?!

```
model = Pipeline([
        ('feat', FeatureUnion([
            ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='char', ngram_range=(3, 5), min_df=0.01, lowercase=True, tokenizer=tokenizeTfidf)),    
        ])),


        ('pip1', Pipeline([('clf1', GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=1000, random_state=7))])),
        ('pip2', Pipeline([('clf2', SVC())])),
        ('pip3', Pipeline([('clf3', RandomForestClassifier())])),
        ('clf', VotingClassifier(estimators=["pip1", "pip2", "pip3"]))
    ])

clf = model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

but I got this error:

```
 ('clf', VotingClassifier(estimators=["pip1", "pip2", "pip3"])),
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\imblearn\pipeline.py", line 115, in __init__
    self._validate_steps()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\imblearn\pipeline.py", line 139, in _validate_steps
    "(but not both) '%s' (type %s) doesn't)" % (t, type(t)))
TypeError: All intermediate steps of the chain should be estimators that implement fit and transform or sample (but not both) 'Pipeline(memory=None,
     steps=[('clf1', GradientBoostingClassifier(criterion='friedman_mse', init=None,
              learning_rate=0.1, loss='deviance', max_depth=3,
              max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
              min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
              min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
              min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=1000,
              presort='auto', random_state=7, subsample=1.0, verbose=0,
              warm_start=False))])' (type <class 'imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline'>) doesn't)
```

Comment: Please post the complete code? Which Pipeline are you importing?

Comment: Secondly, a Pipeline is sequential. And all the classes inside it should be transformers (except the last one, which can be an estimator also). The output from first `transform()` goes to input of second `fit()`, output of second `transform()` goes to input of third `fit()` and so on... What do you expect to be input of `'pip2'`?

Comment: how could I using voting classifier inside a Pipeline !?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am assuming you want to do something like this:

1) Transform the text data to tfidf using TfidfVectorizer
2) Send the transformed data to the 3 estimators (GradientBoostingClassifier, SVC, RandomForestClassifier) and then use voting to get the predictions.

If this is the case, this is what you need.

```
model = Pipeline([
        ('feat', FeatureUnion([
            ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='char',  
                                      ngram_range=(3, 5), 
                                      min_df=0.01, 
                                      lowercase=True, 
                                      tokenizer=tokenizeTfidf)),    
        ])),
        ('clf', VotingClassifier(estimators=[("pip1", GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=1000, 
                                                                                 random_state=7)), 
                                             ("pip2", SVC()), 
                                             ("pip3", RandomForestClassifier())]))
    ])
```

Also, if you are only using the single `TfidfVectorizer` and not combining any other features with it, you dont even need the `FeatureUnion`:

```
model = Pipeline([
        ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='char',  
                                  ngram_range=(3, 5), 
                                  min_df=0.01, 
                                  lowercase=True, 
                                  tokenizer=tokenizeTfidf)),    
        ('clf', VotingClassifier(estimators=[("pip1", GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=1000, 
                                                                                 random_state=7)), 
                                             ("pip2", SVC()), 
                                             ("pip3", RandomForestClassifier())]))
    ])
```